# Grails/Spring Data Binding Map of Objects

Tags: spring, grails, data-binding

I am having problems data binding to my command object that has a map of objects. This is my command object:

```
class SaveEntries {
    Map<Integer, EntryRow> entryRows = new HashMap<Integer, EntryRow>()
    String name
}

class EntryRow {
    int systemID
    def hours = ["","","","","","",""]
}
```

This is my controller code:

```
def save() {
    println request.parameters
    println params
    def saveEntries = new SaveEntries()
    bindData(saveEntries, params)
    saveEntries.entryRows.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v.systemID}" }
    println saveEntries.name
}
```

And this is my form:

```
<form action="main/save">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="test"/>
    <input type="text" name="entryRows[0].systemID" value="1"/>
    <input type="text" name="entryRows[0].hours[0]" value="5"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Finally, this is the output that I get:

```
[entryRows[0].systemID:[1], name:[test], entryRows[0].hours[0]:[5]]
[entryRows[0].systemID:1, entryRows[0]:[systemID:1, hours[0]:5], name:test, entryRows[0].hours[0]:5, action:save, format:null, controller:main]
test
```

As you can see, the entryRows map is not getting populated with anything. I am able to get a Map to populate if I use name="entryRows['test'] value="test", but once I try using an object for the key, the data binding fails.

Can anyone see where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: which version of grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.3.6